# Find the solution of this integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have to solve this differential equation:

[image: differential equation]

After following the necessary steps, I have come to a point where I can't solve this integral:

[image: Integral]

Could you please help me?

Comment: Show us all of the steps you made

Comment: What is, by definition, $e^{\ln|\cos x|}$ ?

Comment: What are $t$ and $g$?

Comment: @Jan Earland It's $\tan$

Answer (score 2):

Your equation can be easy solved if we multiply both sides by $\cos x$, so we have:
$$
y'\cos x-y\sin x=1
$$
and, noting that $-\sin x=\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos x$, we have:

$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(y \cos x \right)=1
$$
i.e. $$y \cos x= x+c$$

Answer (score 1):

One would say that
$$
e^{\large \ln|\cos x|}=|\cos x|
$$ where both sides exist, thus you have to evaluate
$$
\int \frac{|\cos x|}{\cos x}\:dx.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Am I allowed to solve it as the integral of xdx?

Comment: @snitchben I think you mean $\int1dx$ or $\int(-1)dx$.

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: so, it should have two solutions?

Comment: @snitchben It depends on the set you are integrating over.

Comment: Thanks? I should thank you lol